# Linked List Stack, push to the bottom not top

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I'm learning about LinkedLists and stacks in java, and came across a problem. at the moment I have a push function, which puts an object at the top of the stack. I'm trying to figure Turned out how to do the opposite and push an object to the bottom, without losing the links in the list.

To help you understand my issue better here are some parts.

The object Constructor:

```
 //Variables
public int planeID;         //unique plane identifier
public String destination;  //destination
public String airline;      //airline name
public String aircraft;     //aircraft type
public double time;         //arrival or departure time
public Plane next;          //next plane in terminal

// Plane Constructor
public Plane (int i, String dest, String airl, String airc, double t) {

        planeID = i;
        destination = dest;
        airline = airl;
        aircraft = airc;
        time = t;

}// END Plane Constructor
```

Inserting last item (not working code) EDITED

public void insertLast(int i, String dest, String airl, String airc, double t) 
{ // make new link
    Plane newPlane = new Plane(i, dest, airl, airc, t);
    Plane temp = first;

```
while (temp.next != null) {
    temp = temp.next;
}

temp.next = newPlane;
}
```

And finally the push, where the list refers to my LinkedList:

```
 public void push(int i, String dest, String airl, String airc, double t) // put item on top of stack
{
    theList.insertLast(i, dest, airl, airc, t);
}
```

So, now I'm trying to create a new function, lets say insertLast which will insert element it is best to the bottom of the list instead of top, so I can modify my push use queues for this.

**EDIT:**
Turned out it is best to use queues for this.

Comment: Please do not remove the content of your question. We are in the process of reverting the edit so the answers still make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is the [singly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list). If you want to insert the item to the end of this list, then you have to go all the way down, to the last item in your list and assign new Plane to its `next` reference. The last item in the list is the item which `next` reference is `null`.
Or, as another variant, you can keep two links - one for the first item in the list, and one for the last item. That way, you don't need go go all the way down when yon need to add something in the end of the list. It'll be [double-ended list](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/DoubleEndedListslistwithfirstandlastreferences.htm) (don't mix it with the *Doubly linked list*, which is another data structure).

Comment: I think, he needs to check if Node has a reference ( is this is not null), if not : there is a last node, so you need to make your last node reference to your new node.

Comment: @Ernusc yes, this is how you find the last element - its `next` reference is null.

Comment: @aga I modified my question and included code I came up with after reading sources you provided, however it is still not working, and I honestly don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

As you're learning Java, I won't just give you the code, so I've written some pseudo-code.

```
function insertLast(item) {
    tmp = first
    while (tmp.next != null) {
        tmp = tmp.next
    }
    // now we're at the bottom
    tmp.next = item
    item.next = null
}
```

What you have to do is from the first element, keep getting the `.next` until it is null, then add the reference to your new object at the end of the list.

Comment: Correct but a horrible design if you need to do it often.

Comment: Efficiency wasn't part of the question. There's no way to get around worst case O(N) insertion for a singly linked list.

Comment: @Samuel O'Malley so what is your suggestion to make it better?

Comment: @Ernusc Doubly linked list.

Comment: Well if all we consider is the insertLast function then we could maintain a tail reference so that we can quickly perform the insert.

Comment: @That's true, but it's not that difficult to add a back-reference to each node

Comment: True but it depends on how you are going to use it. If all you are doing is pushLast and popLast then why not just reverse the list and do push/pop from the front. If all we do is pushLast and popFront then all we need to do is maintain that tail reference.

Comment: @DerFlatulator hey, I updated my answer with code I tested following your logic, but it is not working for me, I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Make sure that `next` is going in the correct direction.